# Создать статический метод sumDigits, чтобы он считал сумму цифр в числе и возвращал сумму в результате своей работы

Tags: java

Нужно реализовать статический метод `sumDigits`, чтобы он считал сумму цифр в числе и возвращал сумму в результате своей работы. Для реализации метода желательно использовать методы:

- класса Integer: `toString()`, `parseInt()`;
- класса String: `charAt()`, `length()`, `valueOf()`.
  У меня получился такой код:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(sumDigits(5059191));
    }

    public static int sumDigits(Integer number)
    {
        String i =  Integer.toString(number);
        char[] chars = i.toCharArray();
        int i1 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[5]);
        int i2 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[0]);
        int i3 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[5]);
        int i4 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[9]);
        int i5 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[1]);
        int i6 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[9]);
        int i7 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[1]);
        int sum = i1+i2+i3+i4+i5+i6+i7;
        return sum;
    }
```

То есть я в жалких попытках посчитать сумму цифр в числе "5059191".
Однако мне выдаёт ошибку: `*"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 out of bounds for length 7".*`
Можете подсказать где я накосячила?

Answer (score 1):

Вот в этой строке

```
int i6 = Character.getNumericValue(chars[9]);
```

вы обращаетесь к элементу массива номер 9, а вашем массиве только 7 значений.

И вообще в вашем методе происходит какая-то дичь. Вам нужно написать метод вроде такого:

```
int sum = 0;
 
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]);
}

return sum;
```

Ну и в догонку исходя из того, что у вас написано вы видимо не совсем понимаете концепцию массива. Вам стоит подумать и почитать на тему что значит запись

```
Character.getNumericValue(chars[5]);
```

Comment: А можете посоветовать что лучше почитать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Ну не знаю, про массивы в целом. Как они работают, как к ним обращаться. Тут нет конкретного какого-то чтива

Answer (score 1):

Переводить int в char или string - так себе идея. Все проще:

```
public static int sumDigits(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        sum += number % 10;
        number/=10;            
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Если хотите конвертировать в стринг и обратно, то примерно так:

```
public static int sumDigits(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (String s : String.valueOf(number).split("")) sum+=Integer.valueOf(s);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: По заданию: "Внутри метода нужно сделать из этого числа строку. Дальше в цикле проходим по каждому символу этой строки, получаем его числовое значение и прибавляем к общей сумме. Затем возвращаем полученную общую сумму"
Я изначально сделала именно так, однако оказалось, что неверно.

Comment: @Юлия я, конечно, ответ дополнил, но мне всегда было интересно, кто дает такие "задания". во всех вопросах одна и та же аргументация: так делать нельзя, можно только через одно место...